# Ghostscript txtwrite bbox limits

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, bounding-box, pdf-parsing

When I use `ghostscript` with `textwrite` device, I'm getting an `XML` file that describes my `pdf`, i.e

```
<page>
    <block>
        <line>
            <span bbox="95 97 357 97" font="..." size="9.0000">
                <char bbox="95 97 106 97" c="a"/>
                <char bbox="106 97 117 97" c="b"/>
                <char bbox="117 97 126 97" c="c"/>
                ...
            </span>
        </line>
    </block>
    <block>
    ...
```

My question is if there is a known scale to the bbox (bounding-box) coordinates `(X1,Y1,X2,Y2)` or are they page dependent? in any case, can I fetch the page grid in any way to understand its height and width?

My main point here is too understand features like if the character was positioned beyond the center of the page etc.

My full command to convert `pdf` to `XML`:

```
ghostscript -q -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -r200 -sDEVICE=txtwrite" -sOutputFile=<output-path.xml> -dTextFormat=1 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE <input-path.pdf>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bounding box is in PostScript/PDF units, 1/72 inch. Note that the output isn't really XML, its 'like' XML.

Comment: ok, so since I'm using `sPAPERSIZE=a4`, looking at https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/current/Use.htm#Known_paper_sizes I can see it is W=595 , H = 842